# Bootstrap glythicons not showing when hex code used

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ill start with what I've done thus far:

Re-downloaded fonts

switched to CDN for bootstrap css

declared font in custom css file that i use for all my styling

If i use the traditional span that works e.g

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

I can also see the like default icon the browser puts there

Code:

```
 .box-cont li:before {
  content:"\e013";
  }
```

my website is ukhotspot.co.uk it is obvious what's going on hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have to add the font-family to the selector:

```
.box-cont li::before {
  content: "\e013";
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
}
```

If you don't do this, the browser try to use a fallback font and there is no custom icon.

You can also add the class `.glyphicon` to every element but the first one should be the simpelst solution.